# deactivating/activating a UGUI button leaves it in pressed state

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a button with "animation" transition type. When I click it, I call `SetActive(false)` on its gameObject. Then, by clicking another button, I call `SetActive(true)` to activate the deactivated button, but the animation does not reset: it's still in pressed state (like it was when I deactivated it, because I was pressing it), and it does not back to idle state.

EDIT: I realized I have not set the sprite for "normal" state in the animation. But I don't understand why before deactivate/activate, the button is showing default sprite for idle state, and after deactivate/activate, is showing pressed sprite for idle state.

Comment: I don't know the behaviour that you are trying to achieve but i think that SetActive is not what you should use... The "interactable" bool seems more appropriate to just disable a button

Comment: I want to hide it too, so SetActive(false) is what i want. I'm having the same issue with other game objects, not only buttons. Other developers are having same issue -> http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/impossible-to-maintain-animator-default-values-in-all-scenarios.394618/

Comment: Yes. Please find more info about this issue in this thread in Unity forums: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/write-defaults-confusion-bug.392058/#post-2593041